# How do I know if my project is using Azure Shared Cache?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Azure Shared Caching is to be deprecated 1st Sept 2014.

I have been asked to evaluate if a project that I did not build utilizes the Azure Shared Cache.

I know the project does use a form of Azure Caching but I am struggling to identify which one.

How would I know if we use it or not?

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg618005.aspx):

To create **and manage caches**, you must go to the Cache section.
On the main page of the Management Portal, click Service Bus, Access Control, & Caching at the bottom of the left pane. In the left pane, expand Services, and then click Cache.

I am not sure if this info is still actual.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question asked; it just explains how to use the old portal to manage caches. Even if the OP found one there, that doesn't mean the app is using it (there's no linkage between app and cache stored in that portal). The OP is asking how to specifically determine if the app in question is using shared caching.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure Shared Cache, more than likely it will be configured in web.config. That would be the 1st place to start. Under `<dataCacheClients>` section there look for the following:

```
<host name="yourcachename.cache.windows.net" cachePort="22233" />
```

If you're using this, then you're definitely using shared caching.

You may also find this link useful for further identification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg278342.aspx as this link lists down other options as well.